# Does event listeners like keyup/down need to be disposed in java?

Tags: java, swt, listener, event-listener, keyup

I created one event listener on my `combobox` in

```
 java SWT as: 

cbInstrumentType.addListener(SWT.KeyUp, (event) -> {});
```

Does listeners like `keyup/ keydown/  keyPressed/ selectionListener and others` need to be removed or disposed of?

If yes, how?

Comment: You can remove the listeners as simple as calling removeListener.
I do not know the swt but i'm assuming that once you dispose / stop using the element for which you created listeners all of those listeners will be disposed too.

It depends on logic of your application whether you should remove them, in most cases you do not need to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listeners do not need to be removed when the control is disposed.

The control dispose removes all listeners automatically since it deletes the event table that contains the listeners list. See the `Widget.releaseWidget` method.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever we close a part control `Dialog` in swt, listeners are disposed of with the Dialog automatically.

Comment: This generally isn't necessary. The control dispose already deals with this.